Ive sent Solana to the Slothana wallet
But I didnt see Slothana back in my trade history. It will be airdropped but there has to give you already the amount that you will get  Could you check for me if I will get the coins?
https://solscan.io/tx/3FxKBe7NLNZS3XFE4Bw8hLJrMXadbW41WYAFb7mJX226zEjNmXMkV3Gr1Jz1hxq8nhhx9V6F4hMh16wsLHxKUgQX!
